# How to send message with viber bot to group chat?

Tags: node.js, viber, viber-bot, viber-api

Im trying to make a vibe bot that will only send announcements to group of people. The bot will not respond or interact with anyone, as its only and primary task is sending given text as an announcement to a group of people in the same chat.

I don’t understand:

a. What is wrong?
b. Why its not working?
c. Where to find the viber chat id?
d. Can I hook up this bot to any chat group (group/community/channel)?

```
     const ViberBot = require('viber-bot').Bot;
    const TextMessage = require('viber-bot').Message.Text;
    
    
    const viberBot = new ViberBot({
    authToken: process.env.VIBER_AUTH_TOKEN,
    name: "...name...",
    avatar: "...img-url..."
    });
    
    
    viberBot.sendMessage({ id: process.env.VIBER_GROUP_ID }, new TextMessage("hello world!"))
```

I triple-checked the auth tokens, and it's correct. But I still can't find the Viber Chat Id.

I tried to get the ending of a share link (to use it as the chat id), and the result I got was the following error:

```
    {
      status: 10,
      status_message: 'webhookNotSet',
      chat_hostname: 'SN-CHAT-16_'
    }
    {
      status: 10,
      status_message: 'webhookNotSet',
      chat_hostname: 'SN-CHAT-20_'
    }
    {
      status: 10,
      status_message: 'webhookNotSet',
      chat_hostname: 'SN-CHAT-10_'
    }
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to achieved with Viber.
Here is another discussion on the topic: https://github.com/Viber/sample-bot-isitup/issues/2

An alternative dirty hack solution would be to ramp up a virtual machine and using automation for windows to make it so that a Viber client is running and you send the messages to the group via the Windows Viber UI.